# PyCharm Doesn't Recognize Installed Package

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pycharm

I'm a beginner level Python user. Up until today I was able to use installed packages(pandas, numpy and so on) at PyCharm. I try to download `BeautifulSoup` and error msg took me to PyCharm web site. I followed instruction on my regular MacBook terminal (`macOS Monterey 12.4`) where it told me to upgrade the `pip` as `pip3` and try the `pip3 install beautifulsoup`. After this code I get this from terminal `Requirement already satisfied`.
However since that update on terminal none of the packages on my PyCharm are working. PyCharm marks it with red underline, I click and choose `install` again but still not working. This is what I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ezgiwon/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import beautifulsoup4
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Also for the rest it's similar to this error `couldn't find __innit__.py`
I've read so many solutions here but some didn't work some I wasn't able to understand with my current knowledge.
I tried the '`edit configurations`', '`edit python interpreter`',also tried the built-in PyCharm terminal to upload those packages. I'm not sure how to fix this issue. I thought I could delete everything following a tutorial and start fresh but seems like I didn't clear all past files.
Now I have a new file under `Library/Framework` for Python which I will be asking in separate question.
Please try to guide me as detailed as possible, much of these terms are new to me and really struggling to run PyCharm correctly. I really need it to run for simple study tasks as I was using it for very basic pandas and numpy calculations.

```
[interpreter][1]

[Paths][2]

[interpreter2][3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Then import like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Yes, I used 'pip install beautifulsoup4' both in MacOS terminal and PyCharm built in terminal. Right now MacOS terminal gives error code `-bash: pip: command not found` . I type in `Python3` first and then`pip install beautifulsoup4` I get another error as `>>> pip install beautifulsoup4
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install beautifulsoup4
        ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> `  My Python3 version shows up as 3.10.5 if that makes a difference.

Comment: You can follow the steps on the [link] (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-beautifulsoup-in-python-on-macos/) or maybe you also need to upgrade your pip as well.